# Deploying Google Cloud SQL Server to Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to deploy with Google Cloud SQL Server as my database. I currently have it working using Google Cloud SQL proxy locally. But obviously to deploy to heroku I cannot do this.

Below is someone that says they have a solution to this problem.
https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/emartech/heroku-buildpack-cloud-sql-proxy#buildpack-instructions

I was able to run their solution, but now I am having a different issue. I am getting this error from heroku when trying to connect to the database:

[image: error]

Before I was getting an ENNOENT error so this is a good sign, but how could I possibly fix this error?

Comment: As far as I understand, you are using a Google Cloud SQL for SQL Server instance database. The [guide](https://github.com/emartech/heroku-buildpack-cloud-sql-proxy) that you are following is using Cloud SQL for PostgreSQL instance as it says: "Google Cloud SQL instance set up with a postgresql user able to connect to the database". This may be the issue.  Also it is best practice to follow the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app) on how to connect to Cloud SQL from external applications, which is not currently available for Cloud SQL for MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like something is wrong with the proxy being run in the buildpack. Is it possible to provide logs from it so we can help you further?